# How to design Flask URL path with '/'

Tags: python, url, flask

In my first Flask application, I am experimenting with URLs that end with a slash vs. those that don't and am seeing some unexpected browser behavior.

1. My view function is just like this:

   ```
   @app.route('/hello')
   def hello_world():
       return 'Hello World!'
   ```

   Then I can go to `127.0.0.1:5000/hello` and see "Hello World".
2. I change the URL to:

   ```
   @app.route('/hello/')
   def hello_world():
       return 'Hello World!'
   ```

   Then I can go to `127.0.0.1:5000/hello` but the browser redirects to `127.0.0.1:5000/hello/`.
3. I change the URL *back* to `/hello`:

   ```
   @app.route('/hello')
   def hello_world():
       return 'Hello World!'
   ```

Then I can not access either `/hello` *or* `/hello/`. When I visit `127.0.0.1:5000/hello`, the **browser still redirects** to `127.0.0.1:5000/hello/` and the response is a 404. I cannot see anything unless I rollback to step 2.

What is going on?

Comment: what error is flask outputtting exactly?

Comment: Flask possibly did a 301 (permanent redirect), which is cached by the browser. Can you trace the status code of the response to 127.0.0.1:5000/hello?

Comment: Yes, [that is exactly what Werkzeug is doing under the covers](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/3006051659821ceb0a0ba453a81efae3e9b64f90/werkzeug/routing.py#L223-L238)

Comment: There has no errors, the browser only view 404 page.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from a (slightly modified) [section of the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#variable-rules):

> #### Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior
>
> Though [your rules] look rather similar, they differ in their use of the trailing slash in the URL definition. In [your step #2], the canonical URL for the [hello_world] endpoint has a trailing slash. In that sense, it is similar to a folder on a file system. Accessing it without a trailing slash will cause Flask to redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.

What this means is that Flask in step #2 will redirect the `/hello` URL using a [301 Moved redirect](https://httpstatuses.com/301).  This is a permanent redirect and most browsers will cache it.  This is why, even when you change your *code* (in step #3) the browser will still request `/hello/` even though you asked for `/hello` (since when it did so for step #2 Flask told it that `/hello` has *moved* to `/hello/`.)

The simplest solution in such cases is to clear your browser's cache - that removes the "memory" of the redirect and things will work again.

Personally, I use `/directory/` style URLs for resources which would be expected to contain other resources and `/leaf` for resources which have no further sub-resources.

Comment: Can apply to Django?like`url(r'^grid/$', ...),
    url(r'^grid/leaf/', ...),` recommend change to `url(r'^grid/$', ...),
    url(r'^grid/leaf', ...),` ?

Comment: Yes, Django has an [`APPEND_SLASH` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) that the [`CommonMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware) uses to perform similar behavior.